# Not a weight loss ad!

Tags: cryptic-clues

Lose weight dramatically, becoming muscular (5)

Hint:

> Tom's first guess has correctly identified the anagrind and definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third time lucky

> SWOLE

Wordplay is

> LOSE + W (abbrev. of weight) the anagrind is dramatically becoming definition muscular.

---

A second more robust try:

> STOUT - muscular

With word play

> st as abbreviation for stone(s) as in pounds (lb) and ounces (oz)
>  st + out : means stone(s) out (of you) which is to lose weight dramatically.

---

First try: 
Running with this:

> TONED - having firm and well-defined muscles.

If this wordplay is fit:

> de-ton: anagram (clued by dramatically), where [de](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/de) - means lose and ton is a weight.

Recover the endless well-being (6)

Comment: That would be an indirect anagram, so, no. I won't write the answer to your clue in a comment, so I will drink it instead ;)

Comment: Another one which is more black and white. I will drink it too - sláinte :P

Comment: Very clever, but still wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

is it :

> a-diet or diets ? -> some crosswords don't show word breakups to keep it challenging not sure if you have done the same or not

Comment: Sorry, no. It's one five letter word.